# How can I run Python script once a day if computer is on and it has a connection to the Internet?

Tags: scripting, cron, python

I would like to run a Python script every day if my computer is on and it has been connected to the Internet. How can I do it? My effort is

```
00 14 * * * python3 /home/jaakko/.config/spyder-py3/temp.py
```

But the problem is that I don't know if my computer is on on that time and if it has an access to the Internet.

Comment: When you say "if my computer is on," do you mean the computer running this script? If so, cron jobs won't run if the machine is off at their appointed time (this is one of the benefits of [anacron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anacron), which can move jobs to run even if the system was offline when a job was originally scheduled.) As far as internet connectivity, why not just add error handling for that condition to the python script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `anacron` instead of `cron`. In `/etc/cron.daily`, create a file (I'll call it `script`) with these contents:

```
#!/bin/sh
while true; do
    for host in www.ieee.com www.stackexchange.com; do
        if ping -w 4 $host; then
            python3 /home/jaakko/.config/spyder-py3/temp.py
            exit 0
        fi
    done
    sleep 60
done
```

Make it executable by `chmod +x script` and you're done.

It will `ping` domains and run python if a response is received in 4 seconds. Choose the domains that best suit your needs. The ones I provide are just examples, but for general Internet access they will probably be enough.

If no packet is received, it will try again in 60 seconds.

---

**Take note**: The `script` will be run as root. If that is a problem for you, you can follow the steps presented in [this answer in AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/a/235090) to run it as your normal user.

Comment: But don't ping some random server. When you say in connected to the internet, what do you mean? If I ask is my house connected to the road? Is it OK that I can get 50 yards down the road, or that I can get to one house on the other side of the world, but no where else? Ask what is it that I need to be connected to?

Comment: Isn't your personal `crontab` running with `anacron` too (assuming you have `anacron` installed)? Because I don't see the point of using `/etc/cron.daily` and add some potential security issue as now his script is running as root.

Comment: In your while loop, you should sleep like 10 seconds before trying again. There is not point is constantly running ping. Also you probably want to try for N minutes or hours and then stop. It's likely to block any CRON script that comes after, too.

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor Since he used the term Internet (capital I), he probably means "get to the Internet backbone", which is what most people mean when they say "connect to the Internet", even if they don't know it. But agreed, pinging a single random server could be misleading if the server happens to be down, I hope the answer is better now.

Comment: @Quasímodo I can get to the airport, but all flight are cancelled. Success? (Yes I know what the OP was asking for, but with 20 years of software engineering , and requirements analysis experience. I know that what a customer asks for and what they want are not the same thing.)

Answer (score 0):

You can also use simple GUI apps like *kalarm* or *kclock* (available with KDE desktop). Set it up to call your script on desired schedule, I'm using it to daily backup my repositories for instance. And it does not require any super or root access.

Edit: This may assumes that the user is logged in and keeps his session active, I'm not 100% certain about that.

Comment: Do these work if the user is not logged in? Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your answer to make it clearer and more complete.